# How to wrap text in image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello! Can anybody explain, how to reach that effect in HTML/CSS or HTML5/CSS3/JS?**

I have result just when text in image, or text on background, together don't work.
Using the image, as clipping mask.

**Example:**

Variant [one fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iKeler/pR9FA/):

Variant [two fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iKeler/RVmVt/):

Variant three:

## **I need, need to combine both options**

[image]

How I can locate text in image, and background with text together? Thanks a lot!

```
Links to jsFiddle code
```

Comment: Not really clear and it's advisable that you prepare a jsfiddle out of it

Comment: Can you simulate the same on jsfiddle jsfiddle.net

Comment: SVG would be more helpful to render this kind of effect.

Comment: What kind of browser support are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution could be using [`-webkit-mask-image`](http://jsfiddle.net/NULN4/).